# How to update telegram timer object in mongo db using pymongo and retrieve same object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This is how i used to  update a timer object in mongo db using pymongo

```
collection.update_one (
        {'chat_id':update.message.from_user['id']},
        {
            "$set": {
                "telegram_timer_object": Binary(dill.dumps( j.run_once 
          ( Time_out_function, QUESTION_TIMEOUT, context=chat_id )  ))
            },

        }
    )
```

And while retrieving objects are changed and not same

```
jobqueue_object = dill.loads(collection.find_one ( {'chat_id': 
update.message.from_user['id']} )['telegram_timer_object'])

jobqueue_object.schedule_removal()
```

How to resolve it ...???

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)  using `new` option instead of `update_one` that return an instance of [UpdateResult](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult) to get the same object updated at the same time.

Maybe this can help you.

[Pymongo doc related](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.8/api/pymongo/collection.html)

Comment: but i want to store and retrieve the same object eg:<__main__.OurClass object at 0x7fe90891f748> previous case its changes